# Alert on All Items added automatically and erroneously on item insert or update

Tags: 2010, list, alert

When a specific user adds or updates an item in a specific list, an alert automatically created for that user, set to notifiy them of changes/inserts to "All Items". This shouldn't be happening, but for this one user, it is. If we delete the alert, and the user goes back to the list and creates another item, the alert is created again. Why would this be happening? And to only one user (apparently) ?

Update: OK, no custom event receivers on the list or on the site. Here is the spalert object in powershell. This alert is different than all others because it has a blank alerttemplatename and alerttemplate. (All other alerts have a template and templatename.)

- Title             : Action Items: All items
- AlertTemplateName :
- AlertTemplate     :
- Filter            :
- Properties        : {}
- ID                : 1bba691e-a8d0-462d-8eb0-573b2ea9e573
- ListID            : fe119f4f-8e6e-4839-bc14-30e8dc17bbd9
- MatchId           :
- ItemID            :
- ListUrl           : Lists/Action Items21
- List              : Action Items
- Item              :
- AlwaysNotify      : False
- DeliveryChannels  : Email
- AlertType         : List
- EventType         : All
  EventTypeBitmask  : -1
  AlertFrequency    : Immediate
  AlertTime         :
  Status            : On
  User              : NCxxx\cfxxxx
  UserId            : 849
  DynamicRecipient  :

Comment: Is this an Alert or a Workflow Email?

Comment: No event receivers by any chance added by custom developments or 3rd party components?

Comment: Dave, the issue is with alerts being unexpectedly added. But, there are workflows attached to the list.  The workflows are simple Designer types, send email on status change.

Comment: C. Marius, I'll look into custom event receivers. Why do you think this could the source of the issue? And only for one user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind. There was a custom feature installed in the site back when it was in 2007, and it was enabled by default after the migration to 2010.